# Getting BSOD on XP installation

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

I am getting Blue screen during XP installation.
Sometimes it comes up as **PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA** and sometime it comes as **IO1_INITIALIZATION_FAILED** during installation.

I could not make out how they differ in code on restarts. Going through different posts I came to make out that it might be the memory issue.

Setup starts and sometimes comes upto create and delete partition screen and sometimes it
just gets the blue screen. I have deleted my partitions and have two hard disks one of 40gb
another of 200gb with 1gb RAM(DDR2).

Could someone please suggest for any possible measures which can be taken. I think last option would be to change memory instead.

Comment: If you deleted the paritions then there is not much you can do at this point.  This sounds like a memory problem.

Comment: @Ramhound When I first got the chance to advance upto partion and install I did partitioned it. After that either I get BSOD while selecting the partition where I would like to install the OS or at the very beginning of the set up process.